# C++ - Converter Mat para array de inteiros em Opencv?

Tags: c++, imagem, matriz, opencv, pixels

Estou fazendo um projeto de manipulação de imagens utilizando o **OpenCV**. Preciso analisar os valores de *pixels* de uma imagem "binarizada", para isto estou tentando converter a minha imagem de arquivo Mat para um `array` de inteiros, mais especificamente uma matriz de inteiros. Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

```
Mat m;
m = imread("C:/Users/Syn/Desktop/filtesteBranco.jpg");

int matriz[this->m.size().width][this->m.size().height]; 
int i, j; 

// inicializar matriz com zeros //
for (i = 0; i < (m.rows); i++){ 
    for (j = 0; j <(m.cols); j++) 
    {
        matriz[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < (m.rows); x++) // varredura da matriz
{
    for (int y = 0; y<(m.cols); y++)
    {
        matriz[x][y] = m.at<uchar>(x,y);    // capturando os pixels
    }
}
```

Porém, ao tentar exibir a matriz e comparar seus valores de inteiros com a imagem, os valores não batem com os devidos pixels nas linhas da imagem original. Estou capturando os valores de *pixels* da forma errada? Alguém saberia a forma correta de se fazer isso? Desde já agradeço.

EDIT:

Abaixo está o teste que estou fazendo, adicionei 3 pixels brancos no inicio e no final da ultima linha da imagem. A imagem em questão possui tamanho 674x35, por isso postei duas imagens com zoom para mostrar o que estou fazendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao imprimir os valores da ultima linha da imagem, obtive os seguintes valores, porém, eles não batem com os pixels da imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os valores iniciais e finais da linha estão completamente errados. Alguém saberia o que pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: Onde está a declaração /definição de "Mat" ? E os valores que não batem, o que são e o que deveriam ser ?

Comment: Olá, está na primeira linha 'Mat m'.

Comment: @JoséX. Editei meu post, espero que eu tenha conseguido explicar melhor o meu problema, Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: "Mat" não faz parte nem da linguagem nem da biblioteca padrão do C++, deve ser do OpenCV então (que não conheço)

Comment: Mat é um tipo de array/container próprio pra imagens, é da biblioteca opencv. Estou usando opencv juntamente com a linguagem c++.

Comment: Você diz que a sua imagem é "binarizada", mas está lendo ela de um jpg e com formato de 3 canais de cor (leia a documentação de [imread](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) - o parâmetro `flags` tem valor default `1`, que por ser >0 indica 3 canais de cor). Isso pode "explicar" parte do seu problema.

Comment: Além disso, o que você está fazendo é totalmente desnecessário. Um `Mat` já é uma matriz de pixels que você pode (deve) usar no seu processamento. Não faz sentido converter para outra estrutura de dados similar.

Comment: A outra possível "parte" do seu problema pode ser que a sua imagem não seja binarizada de fato. Você a criou onde? Se por acaso usou um editor de imagens e optou por desenhar uma linha ao invés de definir o valor pixel a pixel, é bem provável que o editor tenha tentado "suavizar" o desenho da linha (leia sobre [anti-aliasing na Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing)), e por isso você tem alguns valores 2 e 1 (que, numa escala de cor de 0 a 255, são bem próximos do preto).

Comment: Outro problema é que você está misturando size com rows/cols (invertendo na declaração *da sua* matriz). O número de linhas (rows) é na verdade igual ao `height` e não ao `width`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32971309/2896619 É curioso não ter dado erro de acesso inválido a área de memória, já que a imagem tem dimensões com tamanhos bem distintos.

Comment: Mudei o valor da flag de imread para 0, isto resolveu parte do meu problema, realmente ainda ficaram alguns ruidos na imagem, alguns 255 ficaram perdidos no meio de algumas linhas da imagem, porém na imagem nao há nada de ruido, creio que tenha razão, talvez seja o formato da imagem como falou.

Comment: Sobre a imagem ser binarizada, este exemplo com o jpg foi para testar de uma forma mais simples outro problema que estou tendo. Eu estava pegando uma imagem binarizada de fato vinda de Mat com threshold aplicado, porém na hora de listar os pixels, seus valores estao errados em boa parte da matriz. Existe alguma forma de percorrer a matriz Mat linearmente como mat[i][j] e imprimir seus valores, @LuizVieira? Deste modo eu conseguiria identificar melhor o que está acontecendo na imagem.

Comment: JPG não é muito bom para imagens binarizadas, pois esse formato não guarda o mapa de bits mas sim uma compressão. Ele sempre vai gerar lixo. Teste com BMP.

Comment: Aliás, seu programa está compilando mesmo ? Isto aqui `int matriz[this->m.size().width][this->m.size().height]` não deve compilar, porque arrays nativas precisam ter dimensões constantes, e me parece que "m->size" não é constante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A iteração sobre os pixels de uma imagem com `Mat` é feita da forma que você já utiliza mesmo. Eis um programa de exemplo:

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    Mat m;
    m = imread("C:/temp/teste.bmp", 0);

    for(int x = m.rows-1; x < (m.rows); x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < (m.cols); y++)
        {
            printf("%d ", m.at<uchar>(x, y));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Esse programa, lendo a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(ampliada:)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resulta no seguinte:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
```

Mas observe que a imagem, sendo "binária", precisa ser gravada como BMP (Mapa de Bits), de forma que os valores dos pixels sejam diretamente gravados e não qualquer formato comprimido. Observe também que a chamada de `imread` deve ler a imagem em um único canal (por isso o segundo parâmetro como 0).

Se você utilizar JPG, ele pode gerar "pixels" com detalhes inexistentes devido à compressão utilizada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito Obrigado @LuizVieira. Verifiquei as linhas que vc havia mencionado antes também, a ordem do width e height na declaração da minha matriz, ao inverter como vc havia dito, os pixels ficaram corretos agora. De fato eu me confundi no momento de declarar as coisas. Muito obrigado, usarei o arquivo Mat direto para varrer e trabalhar com a imagem, me parece bem mais eficiênte mesmo.